# Handle local notification when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, background, uilocalnotification

Basiccally I'm scheduling a local notification for ringing my alarm at particular time say 8:00 Am. NOw I want to perform a specific task like play sound of alarm when app is in background but without tapping on the notification banner which I recived in the notification list.

I'm using below code, but it works only when i tap the notification banner and get into the app.

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: 
 UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
 {
   print("notification recived in background state")
 }
```

Please help me with the tricky solution to handle my local notification without tapping the banner.

Thanks is Advance.

Comment: Every time notification call specific sound file change?? or custom sound file used?? let me know

Comment: You can only prepare it beforehand with maximum 30s sound file, it probably won't be possible to handle/wake app if system make your app inactive

Comment: I think you should use notification service extension to handle local notification in background. and if you just want to set custom notification sound then you can set this by "content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: "out.caf")"

Comment: @HimanshuPatel user can change the sound as per their choice.

Comment: @DixitRathod can you please share any link or sample code for reference.

Comment: you can refer this link [https://www.pushbots.help/en/articles/1571650-creating-notification-service-extension] for notification service extension integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a sound file which is placed in project bundle

```
let arrayOfSoundFile = ["water.caf","hello.mp3"]
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationStringForKey("Title..",  arguments: nil)
content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationStringForKey("Text Here...", arguments: nil)   

//Custom sound file as par user requriment select file UIPickerView add and select file 

content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: arrayOfSoundFile[0])
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 50, repeats: false)
let identifier = "WakeUp"
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()
center.addNotificationRequest(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
if error != nil {
    print("notification created successfully.")
}
})

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let dictAps = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    print(dictAps)
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this part is working fine I need to play sound of alarm when app is in background but without tapping on the notification banner of the notificatio.

Comment: @SahilDhiman refrence like (https://medium.com/quick-code/local-notifications-with-swift-4-b32e7ad93c2)